# Method which acts as Button listener similar to OnOptionsItemSelected method

Tags: android, button, listener

I want to know if there is a method which acts similar to the `onOptionsItemSelected` method, but instead listening for the Options Menu items, it listens to all the buttons implemented in the UI.

`onOptionsItemSelected()` method :

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected( MenuItem item ) {
    switch( item.getItemId() ) {
        case R.id.item1:
            if( currentPlayer == 1 ) {return true;}
                updateUI( 1 );
            return true;
        case R.id.item2:
            if( currentPlayer == 2 ) {return true;}
                updateUI( 2 );
            return true;
        case R.id.item3:
            if( currentPlayer == 3 ) {return true;}
                updateUI( 3 );
            return true;
        case R.id.item4:
            if( currentPlayer == 4 ) {return true;}
                updateUI( 4 );
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected( item );
    }
}
```

Right now, I'm stuck using this method for every single button, and I have way too many. It will be much cleaner if I can find a method that works like the one above.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        setContentView(R.layout.content_layout_id);

        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // Perform action on click
                }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
 protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
     super.onCreate(icicle);
     setContentView(R.layout.content_layout_id);

     final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_id);
     button.setOnClickListener(this);

  //asign for othe  button if its btn1,btn2,btn3
     btn1.setOnClickListener(this);
     btn2.setOnClickListener(this);
     btn3.setOnClickListener(this);


 }

public void onClick(View v) {
 switch(v.getId() ) {
 case R.id.button_id:
     //put code here for button_id
 break;

 case R.id.button_id_1:
    break;

 default:
     break;
}      
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
View.OnClickListsner buttonListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
publiv oid onClick(View view) {
Swicth(view.getId()) {
your stuff like in your question 
}
}
}
```

And dont forget to add this listsner to every button like this :

```
butoon1.setOnClickListener(buttonListsner);
button2.setOnClickListsner(buttonListsner);
```